# A Movie About A Kid Making Wishes

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

It was years ago, and I was born in 2002.

It starts with a fat kid with an infinite chocolate bar supply in his pockets. It turns out his friend, who is the protogonist of the movie, got a wishbook. In a later scene (the movie isn't chronological and each chapter is divided by a PowerPoint slide. Funny Quentin Tarantino rip off!) the kid gets a wishbook and after asking for a instruction leaflet. He gets a giant house sized instruction book and then he asks for a simplified version that is a fingertip dictionary sized version that simply reads "Make A Wish"

The movie also have a smart blackbox that can change shapes and be any tool which has a consipiarcy big corporate cliche etc. A scene with a microbe obsessed crazy scientist and his son living under a isolated house where they finally get out and try to not breathe the outside air only to realize the outside air is fresh.

Thats all I remember.

Comment: Can you be any more precise with when you may have watched this, or when it may have been released? I'll have a stab at looking for this anyway, but anything you can do to help narrow it down would be appreciated.

Comment: @F1Krazy all I remember is I was young and besides my mom would pirate movies back in the day for me altough we had DVD's like The Voltron etc. I dont remember much about the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably Robert Rodriguez's *[Shorts](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=111959848)*

> In a gambit that seems designed to amuse the filmmaker more than his audience, the story is divided into **five "shorts," which are presented out of order**. The central character is grade-schooler Toby "Toe" Thompson (Jimmy Bennett), who lives with his overworked parents (Leslie Mann and Jon Cryer) and disdainful teenage sister (Kat Dennings).
>
> Toe appears in all the stories, but several of them feature other families in the Thompsons's Texas subdivision, Black Falls. It's a newfangled company town whose residents all work for the same man: greedy, tyrannical Carbon Black (James Spader), who markets **a shape-shifting PDA that can do, well, almost anything**. (Battery life is lousy, though.)
>
> For no reason the movie bothers to imagine, the suburb is suddenly blessed with a magical alternative to the PDA: a rainbow-striped rock that grants wishes. Shock, chaos and mild hilarity ensue as the object passes through many hands. Some people make their wishes carelessly; others idly wish without knowing that the rock will fulfill their request.
>
> Friendless Toe wears braces and is tormented every school day by a gang led by Carbon Black's daughter, Helvetica. (She's played by Jolie Vanier, who might have been cloned from the Addams Family-era Christina Ricci.) Toe and "Hel" contend for the rainbow rock, which is ultimately seized by the girl's father. He, of course, needs to learn a few lessons in humility and humanity.
>
> As the tale hops forward and backward, the magic stone falls temporarily under the control of adventurous Loogie (Trevor Gagnon), who summons crocodiles, cobras and a pterodactyl. (His surname, by the way, is Short.) The rock also creates a Ghostbusters-style monster out of nasal mucus excavated by Nose (Jake Short), the **son of a germophobic scientist** (William H. Macy).

Found with a search for *film wishes instruction book germophobe scientist*

### Trailer